# Laravel with sqlserver show warning mysql has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
"laravel/framework": "^8.0",
```

I'm Using laravel and database using sqlserver, but why in my xampp `error.log` show warning mysql has gone away. even though I don't use mysql at all

```
[Wed Mar 23 08:10:27.486328 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 4772:tid 15840] [client 182.1.191.8:60458] PHP Warning:  Uncaught PDOException: PDO::_construct(): MySQL server has gone away in D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector.php:70\nStack trace:\n#0 D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector.php(70): PDO->_construct('mysql:host=192....', 'username', 'password', Array)\n#1 D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector.php(46): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:host=192....', 'username', 'password', Array)\n#2 D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=192....', Array, Array)\n#3 D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\ConnectionFactory.php(184): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)\n#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Con in D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector.php on line 70
[Wed Mar 23 08:10:27.486328 2022] [php7:error] [pid 4772:tid 15840] [client 182.1.191.8:60458] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector.php on line 46
```

and in my laravel project -> config -> database.php is already remove mysql config.

database.php

```
'connections' => [    
        // 'mysql' => [
        //     'driver' => 'mysql',
        //     'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        //     'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        //     'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        //     'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        //     'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        //     'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        //     'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        //     'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        //     'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        //     'prefix' => '',
        //     'prefix_indexes' => true,
        //     'strict' => true,
        //     'engine' => null,
        //     'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        //         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        //     ]) : [],
        // ],
   
        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ]
    ],
```

and this my env

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=host
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: did you do this `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: I think you have to clear your config, Try `php artisan optimize: clear`.

After that, If you get an error like `could not find driver` means you are not using sqlserv extension for PHP try enabling these extensions `php_pdo_sqlsrv`, `php_sqlsrv`.